# MacOS Photos App: Resizing a Photo

Tags: macos, photos.app, image-editing

I am trying to get used to the Photos App on MacOS, but there’s one thing I can’t find, either in the Help or in all of my web searches.

How can I resize an image? By that I mean scale it down. I can find how to crop the image, but that’s not what I want.

For example, I have a large image, say 1280px x 960px. I would like to scale it to a smaller size, say 640px x 480px. This is the sort of thing you need to do to adjust an image for use on a web page.

I know how to resize using Preview app, and I have other applications which will do the job, but I would like to do it within the Photos App itself.

I will happily install an extension if required.

Comment: I know this may seem strange, but based on my experience people can have a different idea as to what *scaling* an image means. Can you clarify exactly what you mean (or better still, what you're ultimate aim is)? Not trying to be difficult, just wanting to make sure everyone is on the same page. :)

Comment: @Monomeeth I have added a paragraph with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the main reason for your question, but if you wanted to resize an image for use elsewhere (e.g. for use on a web page), you can choose to resize it upon export.

More specifically:

1. Within Photos, select your image(s)
2. Press the <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> keys (or navigate to File > Export > Export Photos...)
3. In the pop-up window that appears, click on the down arrow to the right of the Photo Kind option (see below)

[image]

4. This reveals the Quality, Color Profile and Size options
5. Click on the Size drop-down menu and select one of the preset options **or** choose the Custom option
6. *OPTIONAL:* - If you selected the Custom option at Step 5 you can now specify dimensions for width or height to resize the image
7. Click on the blue <kbd>Export</kbd> button
8. Select the location you want the photos exported to
9. Click on the <kbd>Export</kbd> button

Now your photo(s) have been exported with the size you chose to the location you chose and these are available to other applications (and within the Finder).

**Using 3rd party apps as helpers within Photos**

Depending on the version of macOS (and Photos) you have installed, you can also use 3rd party apps as *helper* apps to edit photos. You can launch these from within Photos, make your edits, and then upon saving the changes appear automatically within the Photos app. This includes scaling changes.

To do this:

1. Right-click (or control-click) on the photo you want to edit
2. Select the Edit With option
3. Select the 3rd party app (e.g. Photoshop etc)
4. The photo you clicked on at Step 1 opens in the 3rd party
5. Make any editing changes you require (including resizing/scaling the photo)
6. Save the changes within the app.

Now your edited photos appear with all changes intact within the Photos app.

**NOTE:** The app you select at Step 3 must already be installed on your Mac for it to be available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It’s not as straight forward as I should have thought, but it does the job nicely. I do have a number of 3rd party apps which will also do the job, including ImageMagic, but I thought I would see what Photos would do itself.